# How can I include a normal method inside Prawn Generate block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, pdf-generation, prawn

In my Rails web application, we are exporting a table of contents to a PDF file. For that we have used Prawn Gem. Earlier I had huge lines of code inside the below given block, but I reduced the lines by putting codes in to different methods:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.generate("#{Rails.root}/#{file_name}") do
   print_pdf_header(report, period)
   map_table_header(parents)
   map_table_content(hash, parents)
   map_table_column_total(parents, hash)
   array.each_with_index do |imagename, _index|
      start_new_page
      image "#{full_path}/#{imagename}.png",
             vposition: :middle, position: :center, width: 500
   end
end
```

> print_pdf_header(report, period), map_table_header(parents),
>   map_table_content(hash, parents), map_table_column_total(parents, hash)

But, these methods I have used inside the Prawn Generate block gets 'undefined method' error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `print_pdf_header' for #<Prawn::Document:0x12f3bcec>)
```

So, please tell me how can I include a normal method inside `Prawn::Document.generate` block?

Thanks for any help offered :)

Comment: where you have defined those methods `print_pdf_header`

Comment: In the same class/file itself..

Answer (score 1):

Prawn's `generate` method is just for very simple documents that don't require access to outside state or methods.

For what you're looking for, you should make use of [Prawn::View](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/Prawn/View.html) instead. It will make it possible to call Prawn's document methods directly, but will also make the methods defined in your object accessible.